# HttpContext.Current is null in Application_PreSendRequestHeaders

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting a null reference exception when starting my application. Here is the HttpContext.Current null.

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    if (response.Filter is GZipStream && response.Headers["Content-encoding"] != "gzip")
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
    }
    else if (response.Filter is DeflateStream && response.Headers["Content-encoding"] != "deflate")
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
    }
}
```

Why is it so and how can i get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade from VS 2008 to VS 2012?

I think you still need to upgrade the web.config file then.

1) Remove this section in the `<configSections>`:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
      <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

2) In the `<compilation>` tag add attribute `targetFramework="4.5"`:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

3) Add the following sections in `<system.web>`:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

4) Remove the `<httpHandlers>` and `<httpModules>` sections from the `<system.web>` section.

5) Remove the `<system.codedom>` section.

Comment: Can you explain why this is?

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but I had the same issue as Djave when I upgraded to VS 2012 and did not update the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

This issue got fixed for me after I changed the application pool's setting "Managed pipeline mode" from classic to Integrated.